# laravel get relation hasMany model with where clause

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have two models:

**Playlist** and **Image**

a playlist can have many images.
One image belongs to a playlist.

In table images I create also a column called "position" which can contains 
integers.

in Playlist.php:

```
public function images(){
    return $this->hasMany('Image');
}
```

in Image.php:

```
public function playlist(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Playlist');
}
```

I select a playlist Model:

```
$playlist = Playlist::with('images')->find($id);
```

**Question:**

How can I select an image from my $playlist with a specific position, per example with position 1?
I want load all images in the controller (to have all images of all positions in view) but in the view I want select a image with a specific position.

With:

```
$playlist->images
```

I get ALL the related images, but I want ONLY the image which has a "1" in the position column.

EDIT:

I got this solution:

in Playlist I create a new function:

```
public function imagePosition($position) {
    return $this->hasMany('Image')->wherePosition($position)->first();
}
```

And now I can select this image in my view with:

```
{{$playlist->imagePosition(1)->id}}
```

Is this the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use eager loading constraints, like so;

```
$playlist = Playlist::with(array('images' => function ($query){
        $query->where('position', 1);
    }))->find($id);
```

This will load up playlists with their images, but only the ones that have a position of 1.

But if you want all the images, you can re-query the result relation like so;

```
$playlist->images()->where('position', 1)->first();
```

Comment: yes this is a good way.. but my problem is that I want load all images in the controller (to have all images of all positions in view) but in the view I want select a image with a specific position... sry for ambiguous description.

Comment: @goldlife Amended answer.

Comment: this answer saved me,thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

```
$users = Playlist::with(array('images' => function($query)
{
   // the condition that will be apply on the with relation

}))->find($id);
```

see [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships) at 'Eager Load Constraints' paragraph